# Android onTouch to handle multiple views

Tags: android, touch, view, drag

I have three TextViews lined up horizontally in a LinearLayout. What I want to do is, when a user starts the touch from the first TextView, passes the second TextView pressed, and finally ends the touch at the third TextView, and all three TextViews should be highlighted with a different background color. I originally tried in this way:

```
    final TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            return true;
        }
    });

    final TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            return true;
        }
    });

    final TextView tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text3);
    tv3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But the result is that all touches, even if I'm ACTION_MOVEing to TextView 2, onTouch() is called on the first TextView. The only thing that comes to my mind to implement this is to attach an OnTouchListener to the parent layout and for each touch event, see if the current touch event is on any child TextViews and change the background color of that child, if any. But I'm wondering if there is an API by android to do so, or there is any clever way to do so.

Comment: can you please post your xml

Comment: still have a problem?

Comment: I didn't check this question until now. Thank you for your replies, but my code was a simple demonstration. The operation is more complex and I solved this problem by adding a blank container and handle all touch events from that container..

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors for each textview

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

secltor drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
</selector>
```

selectedstate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/required_color" />
</shape>
```